# SQL COUNT* GROUP BY bigger than,

Tags: sql, count, group-by

I want to select the distinct keys with the occurence number, this query seems functionate:

```
SELECT ItemMetaData.KEY, ItemMetaData.VALUE, count(*) 
FROM ItemMetaData 
GROUP BY ItemMetaData.KEY 
ORDER BY count(*) desc;
```

But I also want to filter these result, meaning I want only where count(*) is greater than 2500 so only bigger than 2500 occurence will shown, but:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
    SELECT ItemMetaData.KEY, ItemMetaData.VALUE, count(*) 
    FROM ItemMetaData 
    GROUP BY ItemMetaData.KEY 
    ORDER BY count(*) desc
) as result WHERE count(*)>2500;
```

Unfortunately this query results in a syntax error.  Can you help me achieve my requirement?

Comment: Somebody just deleted the post i want to Accept, please wrote it back and i will accept it"SELECT *
FROM
(
   SELECT ItemMetaData.KEY, ItemMetaData.VALUE, count(*) 'ItemsCount' 
   FROM ItemMetaData 
   GROUP BY ItemMetaData.KEY 
) sub
WHERE sub.ItemsCount > 2500
ORDER BY sub.ItemsCount desc;"
Having is also working and naturally all other answer will vote up, thank you, but...

Answer (score 127, accepted):

HAVING clause for aggregates

```
SELECT ItemMetaData.KEY, ItemMetaData.VALUE, count(*) 
FROM ItemMetaData 
Group By ItemMetaData.KEY, ItemMetaData.VALUE
HAVING count(*) > 2500
ORDER BY count(*) desc;
```

Answer (score 18):

You should use `having` with group functions instead of `where`. E.g.:

```
select ..., count(*) from ... group by ... having count(*) > 2500;
```

Answer (score 8):

You do not need to use a subquery - simply use a [`having` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8hhs5f4e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) instead of `where` clause to filter by an aggregated column.

```
SELECT
ItemMetaData.KEY, ItemMetaData.VALUE, count(*)
FROM ItemMetaData
GROUP BY ItemMetaData.KEY
HAVING count(*) > 2500
ORDER BY count(*) desc
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the explanation: `WHERE` clause introduces a condition on individual rows; `HAVING` clause introduces a condition on aggregations.

Use `WHERE` before `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` after `GROUP BY`. It isn't mandatory, but helpuful in most cases.

```
SELECT 
       ItemMetaData.KEY, ItemMetaData.VALUE, СOUNT(*) 
FROM  ItemMetaData 
GROUP BY
       ItemMetaData.KEY, ItemMetaData.VALUE
HAVING СOUNT(*) > 2500
ORDER BY СOUNT(*) DESC;
```