# Python sqlite3 Column1 val has Column 2 val equal to number and also val equal to another number

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

I don't know how to word my question in a way that's searchable so forgive me if this is answered already. I'm not familiar enough with SQL commands to even point me in the right direction. I have a sqlite table that links two other tables. Example:

```
╔═════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║ key ║ SpellKey ║ ClassKey ║
╠═════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║   1 ║        2 ║        2 ║
║   2 ║        2 ║       10 ║
║   3 ║        2 ║       12 ║
║   4 ║        3 ║       10 ║
║   5 ║        3 ║       12 ║
║   6 ║        4 ║        2 ║
║   7 ║        4 ║       12 ║
╚═════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

ClassKey and SpellKey are foreign keys. The goal is to find all SpellKey's that have ClassKey=2 AND ClassKey=12. The results for the provided dataset should return: 2 and 4.

"WHERE" statements such as "...WHERE ClassKey=2 AND ClassKey=12" don't work because obviously a row cannot be both 2 and 12 at the same time. If possible, I would like a single sqlite3 statement that can do this.

Comment: i think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397757/sql-count-group-by-bigger-than) is what you are looking for

Comment: If it is, then I don't know how to manipulate what they are doing to apply to my situation. "GROUP BY" and "HAVING" statements are typically used with aggregate functions such as count. However, I don't need a count, I need the SpellKey values where a specific unique SpellKey has two rows corresponding to the ClassKeys of 2 and 12 in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution using a "self join" method.

```
SELECT A.SpellKey
FROM TableName A, TableName B
WHERE A.SpellKey = B.SpellKey
AND A.ClassKey=2 AND B.ClassKey=12
```